# BOX api - creating folders + subfolders in iOS

Tags: ios, directory, box-api, subdirectory

In the box api there's a button to make a folder. But i can't figure out how to modify the button to let me make a folder with subfolders included.

what im trying to make:

When you click the Add folder button you get a NSAlert which asks you what name you want to give it. This alert must be modified so it has multiple text bars. In the first bar you can fill in the new folders name. the other (3) you can leave blank for creating no subfolders, or fill in a name to create a subfolder.

Is this possible? I would appreciate every help or hint you can give me!

some code:

```
    #pragma mark - Folder creation - (void)addFolderButtonClicked:(id)sender { UIAlertView *folderNamePrompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Folder" message:@"Name:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

folderNamePrompt.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

[folderNamePrompt show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{ if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) { UITextField *nameField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]; BoxFolderBlock success = ^(BoxFolder *folder) { [self fetchFolderItemsWithFolderID:self.folderID name:self.navigationItem.title]; };

    BoxAPIJSONFailureBlock failure = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSDictionary *JSONDictionary)
    {
        NSLog(@"folder create failed with error code: %i", response.statusCode);
        if (response.statusCode == 409)
        {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIAlertView *conflictAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name conflict" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"A folder already exists with the name %@.\n\nNew name:", nameField.text] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

                conflictAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

                [conflictAlert show];
            });
        }
    };

    BoxFoldersRequestBuilder *builder = [[BoxFoldersRequestBuilder alloc] init];
    builder.name = nameField.text;
    builder.parentID = self.folderID;

    [[BoxSDK sharedSDK].foldersManager createFolderWithRequestBuilder:builder success:success failure:failure];
}
```

Comment: You need to submit a request for each folder. Create the parent first. Once you have its id, you can submit a request for each subfolder, supplying the parent id of the newly created parent.